# Building a Parent child Category Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have managed to create parent and child categories, I am using One table for categories, with fields cat_id, cat_name_cat_parent_id. So its all working. But I want to display these categories inside my product adding page, and It should be displayed as a select box option group values with Parent Category as a title disabled and child categories underneath. as below

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Parent Category 1">
    <option value="1">sub cat 1</option>
    <option value="2">sub cat 2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Parent Category 2">
    <option value="mercedes">sub cat 1</option>
    <option value="audi">sub cat 2</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

by using my cat_model function I can fetch all the categories and their parent category id, but how to group it as I mentioned above and pass to select group

In my controller I am using this function to get all categoies:

```
$this->data['product_categories'] = $this->category_m->get();
```

**UPDAT:::**
I have managed to get this by creating two functions to get parent and child seperately, like this::

```
public function getAllParents();
public function getAllChild($id)
```

and using the second function inside the loop of fist functions result. Is this the proper way to do this, or any another proper ways. I my view file I am using like this::

```
 <optgroup label="<?php echo $parent->category_name; ?>">
      <?php $children = $controller->getAllChild($parent->category_id);
           foreach ($children as $child) { ?>
                   <option value="<?php echo $child->category_id ;?>" 
           <?=set_select('product_category', $child->category_id); ?>><?php echo $child->category_name; ?>
</option>
            <?php } ?>
      </optgroup>
```

Comment: You are talking about in view page how to populate it right?

Comment: yes, in my product adding view file

Answer (score 0):

Use codeigniter's `result_array()` for array format result.Like this..

```
$this->data['product_categories'] = $this->category_m->get()->result_array();
//print_r($this->data['product_categories']);
```

Render your view like this...

```
<select>
<?php foreach ($product_categories as $cat){?>
  <optgroup label="<?php echo $cat['category_name'];?>">
    <option value="1">sub cat 1</option>
    <option value="2">sub cat 2</option>
  </optgroup>
<?php }?>  
</select>
```

**Note:** For subcategories you have to use `join()` between categories and subcategores table.

Comment: I am using a single table for categories as I mentioned in my question like with fields cat_id, cat_name and cat_parent_id, If item is parent cat_parent_id will be 0

Comment: `print_r($this->category_m->get()->result_array();)` post your array.

Comment: by var_dump($this->category_m->get()) I am getting this object arry   ::::::::::  array (size=7)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[40]
      public 'category_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'category_name' => string 'Visiting Cards' (length=14)
      public 'parent_cat_id' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'created_at' => string '2016-12-26 06:23:27' (length=19)
      public 'active' => string '1' (length=1)

Comment: please check my update on question. please let me know Is that the proper way to do this?

Comment: could you please post contents of both functions?

Comment: i used simple query, like this for both::  public function getAllParents()
 {
  $pg = "SELECT * FROM product_category WHERE parent_cat_id = 0";
  $qq = $this->db->query($pg);
  return $qq->result();
 }